# How to get a submodule's root path?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a submodule that has its own routing. Within `app-routing.module` (the top module) it is lazily loaded whenever user goes to URL `/show`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'show',
    loadChildren: './show/show.module#ShowModule'
  }
];
```

From within the ShowModule and its components, how can I find out the *root* of this submodule, which is `/show`?

I need it to construct router link. For example I want to create a link to a top page called 'product' within this Show submodule. The full URL should be `/show/product`. I tried using `<a routerLink="/product">` but the full URL became just `/product`.

I plan to use something like `<a [routerLink]="[rootPath, 'product']">` but don't know how to obtain the 'rootPath' variable.

Comment: set your submodule `NgModel` base url on your component?
like your your module base path is `{path:'/'}.`

Answer (score 0):

create your subModule routes like this so when you call show route automaticaaly it calls showModule '' route, in that if you want create children you can create, but first it calls the ''(empty route)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
   component:''
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but that's not what I asked. I have no problem setting up the routes in the submodule.

Answer (score 0):

The router Array in your ShowModule should be somethink like:

```
const routes:Routes = [
    {
     path: '', 
     component: ShowComponent, 
     children: [ 
        {
           path: 'product,
           component: ProductComponent
        }
     ]
    }
];
```

In some part of the ShowComponent's HTML you need to include the

But if you don't want to have a ShowComponent you can omit it this way:

```
const routes:Routes = [
    {
     path: 'product', 
     component: ProductComponent
    }
];
```

if you want to access from a Component out of ShowModule the routerOutlet must be

```
routerOutlet="show/product"
```

Otherway if you want to access inside the ShowModule the routerModule must be

```
routerOutlet="product"
```

Hope it can help!!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but that's not what I asked. I have no problem setting up the routes in the submodule.